# Spring DI of Constructor parameter with Collection in auto-configure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring-bean

I m wondering about some Constructor injection in spring boot when creating beans .

For example , in spring boot auto-configure , The JacksonAutoConfiguration file

```
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder(ApplicationContext applicationContext,
            List<Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer> customizers) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.applicationContext(applicationContext);
        customize(builder, customizers);
        return builder;
    }
```

where is the Where the List <Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer  comes from?
I dont see any bean declaration about this object. It it not a inter-reference between beans. I m very confused about it.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments in a bean definition are not always "other beans" defined elsewhere, but can be simply "free" arguments. In that case the bean definition is just a method: you call it with the required arguments, and it will return the result.

Because this "free" arguments are not known in advance, you must tell to Spring that:

1. it can't instantiate the bean as a default "singleton", using the scope "prototype"
2. it's about "you" to call the method with the given arguments, usually with the `BeanFactory.getBean(Class cl, Object... arguments)`

In the code you shown, spring-boot will have somewhere a call like this

```java
beanFactory.getBean(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.class, applicationContext, cusomizerList)
```

to be able to istantiate a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean that will be aware of:

- a specific applicationContext (there could be more than one in a Spring application)
- and some 'customizers' to probably let configure in some way the Jackson mapper.

In this way you can obtain a bean that can be built with arguments that are available only at run-time. This is useful in this case at "configuration" run-time, but is a very powerful way to build "smart beans" in your own application.

### Note on 'The evil parts of Spring'

The default behavior of Spring is to build 'singleton' aka `@Service` beans. A singleton bean in a multi-thread application needs to be without fields to be thread-safe.

This brings to a totally 'procedural' design often defeating all advantages of a proper Object-Oriented approach (that needs fields to manage an internal state and offer of course an higher abstraction level).